# how to set pushed view as root view controller using transition

Tags: ios, swift, transition, uipageviewcontroller

i am using page view controller that contain three view controller and one of the view controller has a button on which i used a push view to present another view that comes from right. every thing is working fine and view is animated and present. But the problem is that new view is presented ) over the view that is in the uipageview controller and swipe right present the second page view. i want to open new view using transition as a separate view . So i guess calling it as root vie solves the issue i guess

here is my code

```
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : drawer = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("drawerID") as! drawer

    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    let timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.duration = 0.25
    transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight    //kCATransitionFromLeft
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

code after modifications

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : drawer = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("drawerID") as! drawer
    var nav = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController

    nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:vc )

    hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    let timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.duration = 0.25
    transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight    //kCATransitionFromLeft
    nav!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: appDelegate.navigationController?.setViewControllers([initialViewController], animated: false)

appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = nav
 appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

can you keep those lines above let transition

Comment: thanks @mandeep issue was solved it was because i was calling same view twice...i updated my running code with modifications...thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("drawer")
        appDelegate.navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:initialViewController )
        appDelegate.navigationController?.setViewControllers([initialViewController], animated: false)
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = appDelegate.navigationController
        appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: hello thanks for your comment...i adjusted your code in mine but it make the pushed view blank...kindly check the code in question after merge